# Getting error while installing numpy on a virtual environment on raspberrry pi

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm trying to install numpy on a virtual environment on Raspberry Pi. But I get this error:

```
 Message: During parsing cpu-dispatch: The following CPU features were ignored due to platform incompatibility or lack of support:
      "XOP FMA4"
      Test features "NEON" : Supported
      Test features "NEON_FP16" : Supported
      Test features "NEON_VFPV4" : Supported
      Test features "ASIMD" : Unsupported due to Compiler fails against the test code of "ASIMD"
      Test features "ASIMDHP" : Unsupported due to Implied feature "ASIMD" is not supported
      Test features "ASIMDFHM" : Unsupported due to Implied feature "ASIMD" is not supported
      Configuring npy_cpu_dispatch_config.h using configuration
      Message:
      CPU Optimization Options
        baseline:
          Requested : min
          Enabled   :
        dispatch:
          Requested : max -xop -fma4
          Enabled   : NEON NEON_FP16 NEON_VFPV4
      
      Library m found: YES
      Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.18.4)
      WARNING: CMake Toolchain: Failed to determine CMake compilers state
      Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
      Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
      
      ../../numpy/meson.build:207:4: ERROR: Problem encountered: No BLAS library detected! Install one, or use the `allow-noblas` build option (note, this may be up to 100x slower for some linear algebra operations).
      
      A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-_uu4tel5/numpy_4d71a32207d6416995a682d1d368c8d3/.mesonpy-4q63i79o/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      [end of output]
```

I have also updated cmake and gcc to the last version. I've tried everything but I can't find the solution